# DynamoDB Query Reserved Words using boto3 Resource?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I've been playing around with some "weirder" querying of DynamoDB with Reserved Words using `boto3.resource` method, and came across a pretty annoying issue which I can't resolve for quite some time (Always the same error *sigh*), and can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

My code is the following:

```
import logging
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

TABLE_NAME = "some-table"

def getItems(record, table=None):
  
    if table is None:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
        table = dynamodb.Table(TABLE_NAME)
    
    record = str(record)
    get_item = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key("#pk").eq(":pk"),
        ExpressionAttributeNames={"#pk": "PK"},
        ExpressionAttributeValues={":pk": record},
    )

    logger.info(
        f"getItem parameters\n{json.dumps(get_item, indent=4,sort_keys=True, default=str)}"
    )

    return get_item

if __name__ == "__main":
    record = 5532941
    getItems(record)
```

It's nothing fancy, as I mentioned I'm just playing around, but I'm constantly getting the following error no matter what I try:

`"An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Value provided in ExpressionAttributeNames unused in expressions: keys: {#pk}"`

As far as I understand in order to "replace" the reserved keys/values with something arbitrary you put it into `ExpressionAttributeNames` and `ExpressionAttributeValues`, but I can't wrap my head around as to why it's telling me that this key is not used.
I should mention that this Primary Key exists with this value in the `record` var in DynamoDB.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Key` then just provide the string values and don't be fancy with substitution. See this example:

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/python/WorkingWithQueries/query_equals.py

If you're writing an equality expression as a single string, then you need the substitution. See this example:

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/python/WorkingWithQueries/query-consistent-read.py

Comment: Yes, the adapted code from the second link works, thanks!